# How do I control a python script through a web interface?

Tags: javascript, python, html, raspberry-pi2

For a college project I'm tasked with getting a Raspberry Pi to control an RC car over WiFi, the best way to do this would be through a web interface for the sake of accessibility (one of the key reqs for the module). However I keep hitting walls, I can make a python script control the car, however doing this through a web interface has proven to be dificult to say the least.

I'm using an Adafruit PWM Pi Hat to control the servo and ESC within the RC car and it only has python libraries as far as I'm aware so it has to be witihn python. If there is some method of passing variables from javascript to python that may work, but in a live environment I don't know how reliable it would be.

Any help on the matter would prove most valuable, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a way to handle that situation but I'm not sure how much will it suit for your scenario.

Since you are trying to use a wifi network, I think it would be better if you can use a sql server to store commands you need to give to the vehicle to follow from the web interface sequentially. Make the vehicle to read the database to check whether there are new commands to be executed, if there are, execute sequentially.

From that way you can divide the work into two parts and handle the project easily. Handling user inputs via web interface to control vehicle. Then make the vehicle read the requests and execute them.

Hope this will help you in someway. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry this reply is so late, but your solution pretty much saved my back! There's a bit of latency, but that's pretty much down to the wifi handling in this building.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you out